# Update element from user profile in Meteor

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, meteor-accounts

I am trying to update `firstName` field created in `user.profile` using `onCreateUser`:

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) {
    user.profile = options.profile || {};
    user.profile.firstName = options.firstName;
    return user;
});
```

Also I use allow:

```
Meteor.users.allow({
    update: function(userId, doc, fields, modifier) {
        if (fields === "profile.firstName") {
            return true;
        }
    }
});
```

When I use:

```
Meteor.users.update({
    _id: Meteor.userId()
}, {
    $set: {
        profile: "George"
    }
});
```

It works but it is not what I need.

What I need is to update `firstName`:

```
Meteor.users.update({
    _id: Meteor.userId()
}, {
    $set: {
        profile.firstName: "George"
    }
});
```

But I get this error:

> SyntaxError: missing : after property id

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the [dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/glossary/#term-dot-notation) you need to enclose the whole dotted field name in quotes.

In your case:

```
Meteor.users.update({
    _id: Meteor.userId()
}, {
    $set: {
        "profile.firstName": "George"
    }
});
```

Read more about [updating an embedded field](https://docs.mongodb.org/getting-started/shell/update/#update-an-embedded-field).